# FFmpeg stream encryption

Tags: video, encryption, ffmpeg, stream, video-streaming

I am doing a project where a stream has to be transmitted in real time and in a secure manner to a server.

As it can be found in the documentation it is possible to ''encrypt'' a stream using:

1. srtp https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#srtp

   This works fine but the speed and quality aren't that good. (delay of 3 seconds). I would be grateful for improvements (see below)
2. tls using certificates (https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#tls)

   What exactly does tls? Does it even encrypt or is it just to verify that the stream comes from the correct source?

What else can i use to achieve adequate quality and speed?

---

PS: The command for SRTP with AES with 3 second delay:

```
ffmpeg -r 24 -f x11grab -s 1280x1024 -i :0.0 -c:v libx264 -crf 35 -pix_fmt yuv420p -threads 4 -preset fast -tune fastdecode -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -movflags +faststart -f rtp_mpegts -srtp_out_suite AES_CM_128_HMAC_SHA1_80 -srtp_out_params zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz "srtp://10.0.0.100:8888"
```

I output it with ffplay:

```
ffplay -srtp_in_suite AES_CM_128_HMAC_SHA1_80 -srtp_in_params zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz srtp://client:8888 -fast -fs
```

Answer (score -1):

The differences between the two protocols are very minor and technical, but they are different standards. TLS uses stronger encryption algorithms and has the ability to work on different ports. Additionally, TLS version 1.0 does not interoperate with SSL version 3.0.

Netscape originally developed the SSL (Secure Sockets Layer) protocol to transmit information privately, ensure message integrity, and guarantee the server identity. SSL works mainly through using public/private key encryption on data. It is commonly used on web browsers, but SSL can also be used with email servers or any kind of client-server transaction. For example, some instant messaging servers use SSL to protect conversations.

The Internet Engineering Task Force (IETF) created TLS (Transport Layer Security) as the successor to SSL. It is most often used as a setting in email programs, but, like SSL, TLS can have a role in any client-server transaction.

Comment: Check this:https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/705/what-are-the-differences-between-the-versions-of-tls